# Creating a newsfeed in cshtml

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the following in database

```
status table - status_id, status_body, status_date
student table - student_id, student_username, student_firstname, student_lastname
follow table - followId, follow_followerid, follow_followingid`
```

Now, I want to show the status of the users which a user(say user A) currently follows along with his(user A) own status updates.

How can I do it in cshtml? SQL query for this is necessary.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can't put a sql query in a cshtml file. There is a chain of events that have to happen. You serve the cshtml with only the results of your database query in it. You also need some server-side code to serve the cshtml, for example c# using MVC. And you need a way to access your database, for example an object-relational mapper such as Entity Framework. You have a lot of steps, if you want to make this work.